# Best way of explaining "2.11351E+16"

Tags: html

What is the explanation of this result "2.11351E+16" in excel?

I was calculating a product for the following data

"20 50  10  11  21  30  50  20  52  69  85"

and I arrived at this answer "2.11351E+16".

How can i explain this?

Comment: What do you mean by "explain" here? Are you trying to explain it to others? I would start by referring them to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Comment: You tagged this [tag:html] so why are you talking about Excel? This seems to be more of a question about maths than programming anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
20*50*10*11*21*30*50*20*52*69*85 equals 21.135.114.000.000.000
```

This number is too big for display purposes, so it is expressed as an aproximation. In this case, 2.11351 * 10^16. This aproximation is written as 2.11351E+16 (where E denotes Exponent)
(See [Scientific Notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)).

Answer (score 0):

Excel uses this representation for big numbers by default. This is the scientific notation of the number 21135114000000000.00 which is the product of the data you provided. If you want Excel to show every digit you can format the cell as number manually.